# How to convert hex to int in multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, hex

I am trying to convert a pandas table that has hex values to decimal. I am currently I am doing this one column at a time with the below:

```
df["a"] = df["a"].apply(int,base=16)
df["b"] = df["b"].apply(int,base=16)
df["c"] = df["c"].apply(int,base=16)
df["d"] = df["d"].apply(int,base=16)
```

Anyway to do this all in one go? similar to:

```
df[['a','b','c','d']] = df[['a','b','c','d']].apply(int,base=16,axis=1)
```

I tried:

```
df[['a','b','c','d']] = df[['a','b','c','d']].apply(lambda x: int(x,base=16),axis=1)
```

but this did not work as well.

Sample Data:

```
      A                    B        C
0  0x26  0x526aada8ffd9e0000  0x15f90
1  0x26                  0x0  0x222e0
2  0x25                  0x0  0x222e0
```

Comment: Maybe `df[['a','b','c','d']] = df[['a','b','c','d']].applymap(int, base=16)` ?

Comment: hold on I'll try it now

Comment: can you show some sample data ?

Comment: applymap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base

Comment: sure I'll add it one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a sample dataframe:

```
>>> df
      A                    B        C
0  0x26  0x526aada8ffd9e0000  0x15f90
1  0x26                  0x0  0x222e0
2  0x25                  0x0  0x222e0
```

Now, all you need is `applymap`:

```
>>> hex_to_int = lambda x: int(x, 16)
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].applymap(hex_to_int)
```

And the result is as expected:

```
>>> df
    A                     B       C
0  38  95020000000000000000   90000
1  38                     0  140000
2  37                     0  140000
```

Comment: gives back TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base, but doing it one at a time works...

Comment: @KALEB Are you sure that all of those columns have objects of type `string`?

Comment: I thought the same issue originally, but then running the apply method on each individual column worked like a charm, even tried `lambda x: int(str(x),base=16)` and did not work

Comment: I added some sample data in a csv

Comment: @KALEB Edited my answer. I hope it helps now.

Comment: weird that doing the lambda function inside the apply directly doesn't work